# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.Storage.StorageFile' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

When i return "FileExist" varable in this code i am getting error..

```
public static async Task<bool> FileExistsForWp8(string filename)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;            
        try
        {
            StorageFile FileExists = await folder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            return FileExists;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return FileExists;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you meant 'return true' in try block and 'false' in catch.

Comment: You are expecting a boolean as return. I would try using 'return true' and 'return false'

Comment: Method return type is Task<bool>,but you're trying to return Task<StorageFile>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GetFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfileasync) returns a [StorageFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile).

Thy this:

```
public static async Task<bool> FileExistsForWp8(string filename)
{
    StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;  
    try
    {
       StorageFile File = await folder.GetFileAsync(filename);
       return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```